# Connected components of real Lie groups

Tags: lie-groups, algebraic-groups

(This is a follow-up to [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/333846/shimura-varieties-and-connected-components) of mine.)

Is there an example of a connected reductive algebraic group $G$ over $\mathbb{R}$ such that:

- $G$ is not isomorphic to a product $G_1 \times G_2$ of smaller groups (*isogenous* to a product is OK)
- $G$ is not a torus,
- the quotient of $G$ by a maximal compact-mod-centre subgroup has a complex structure,
- $Z_G(\mathbb{R})$ is not contained in the identity component of $G(\mathbb{R})$?

The condition $Z_G(\mathbb{R}) \subseteq G(\mathbb{R})^\circ$ is vacuously satisfied if $G$ is adjoint, because then $Z_G = \{1\}$; but it is also vacuously satisfied if $G$ is semisimple and simply-connected, because then $G(\mathbb{R})$ is connected as a Lie group by a theorem of Cartan. So any example would have to lie somewhere in between the two (which makes me wonder if there are any examples at all).

PS: Of course $GL_3$ is an example if the "complex structure" condition is dropped.

Comment: Consider $G=SO(m,n)$ with $m\ge 1$, $n\ge 3$ both odd. It's connected, and its center is $\{\pm 1\}$. The group $G(\mathbf{R})$ has 2 components; a maximal compact subgroup is $S(O(m)\times O(n))$ in which we see that $-1$ does not belong to the unit component.

Comment: $G=GL_{3}$ over $\mathbb R$.

Comment: Oops. Of course those are both perfectly good examples. However, I stupidly left out an important (crucial) hypothesis: that $G^{\mathrm{ad}}(\mathbb{R})^\circ$ mod its max compact should have a complex structure. That rules out $GL_3$, and I believe it also rules out YCor's example as well.

Comment: . $G=GO(2,1)$ over $\mathbb R$.

Comment: Isn't $GO(2, 1)$ isomorphic to $PGL_2 \times \mathbf{G}_m$?

Comment: you may be right.

Comment: In my example, $G/K$ has a complex structure when $m=2$.

Comment: @YCor Doesn't your example only work when $m$ and $n$ are both odd?

Comment: @DavidLoeffler oh yes, indeed. Forgot that restriction in between :)

Comment: A silly observation from someone concerned with discrete series:  if $G$ has a compact Cartan subgroup $T$, then $Z_G(\mathbb R)$ is contained in $T(\mathbb R)$, which is a product of circle groups and thus connected.

Comment: Another silly observation: any *semisimple* group of Hermitian type has a compact maximal torus.

Comment: @Borovoi was right. My "example" does not work since it was a product (my proof was ,I thought, long but not difficult. It was also wrong, unfortunately. I have deleted my answer.

Comment: It seems that there is no such example. If $G$ is of Hermitian type and $Z_G(\Bbb R)$ is not contained in the identity component of $G(\Bbb R)$, then $G$ is a product.

Comment: @Mikhail Borovoi, I think it will be useful (certainly to me) to have this as an answer.

Comment: @Venkataramana: OK, but it will take time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is NO such example.

Note that any semisimple algebraic  ${\mathbb{R}}$-group $H$ of Hermitian type has a *compact* (anisotropic) maximal torus. 
Indeed, by a definition of a group of Hermitian type 
(see, e.g., [Deligne, Travaux de Shimura](http://www.numdam.org/item/SB_1970-1971__13__123_0/), condition (1.5.3) on page 128), $H$ is an *inner form* of a compact algebraic $\Bbb R$-group $K$, namely, $H=\,_\sigma K$, where $\sigma={\rm inn}(x)\in {\rm Aut}(K)$,  $x^2=1$, $x\in K^{\rm ad}(\Bbb R)$,
$K^{\rm ad}=K/Z_K$. 
Let $T_K\subset K$ be a maximal $\Bbb R$-torus such that $T_K^{\rm ad}(\Bbb R)$ contains $x$, where $T_K^{\rm ad}=T_K/Z_K$.
Then $T_K=\,_\sigma T_K\subset \,_\sigma K=H$ is a compact maximal torus of $H$.

> **Theorem.** Let $G$ be a (connected) reductive ${\mathbb{R}}$-group. Write $G^{\rm der}=[G,G]$. Assume that $G^{\rm der}$ has a *compact* maximal torus $T^{\rm der}$.
>   If the image of $Z_G({\mathbb{R}})$ in $\pi_0(G({\mathbb{R}}))$ is nontrivial,
>   then there exists a nontrivial split ${\mathbb{R}}$-subtorus $T'\subset Z_G$ and
>   a reductive ${\mathbb{R}}$-subgroup  $G''\subset G$ such that $G=T'\times_{\mathbb{R}} G''$.

*Proof.* 
Write $T=Z_G\cdot T^{\rm der}$; then $T$ is a maximal torus of $G$.
We have maps
$$ Z_G({\mathbb{R}})\to \pi_0(T({\mathbb{R}}))\to \pi_0(G({\mathbb{R}})).$$
Since the image of $Z_G({\mathbb{R}})$ in $\pi_0(G({\mathbb{R}}))$ is nontrivial, we have
$ \pi_0(T({\mathbb{R}}))\neq 1$.

Write $T=T_0\times_{\mathbb{R}} T_1\times_{\mathbb{R}} T_2$,
where $T_0$ is a compact ${\mathbb{R}}$-torus, $T_1$ is a split ${\mathbb{R}}$-torus, and  $T_2\simeq (R_{{\mathbb{C}}/{\mathbb{R}}}{\mathbb G}_{m,{\mathbb{C}}})^{n}$.
We have $\pi_0(T_0({\mathbb{R}}))=1$, and $\pi_0(T_2({\mathbb{R}}))=1$.
Since $\pi_0(T({\mathbb{R}}))\neq 1$, we conclude that $T_1\neq 1$.
Note that the ${\mathbb{R}}$-torus $T/Z_G$ is isogenous to $T^{\rm der}$, and hence, compact.
It follows that $T_1\subset Z_G$.

Set $T'=T_1$ and  $T''=T_0\times_{\mathbb{R}} T_2$; then clearly $T=T'\times_{\mathbb{R}} T''$.
Set $G''=T''\cdot G^{\rm der}$.
Then 
$$T'\cdot G''=T'\cdot T''\cdot G^{\rm der}=T\cdot G^{\rm der}=G\quad \text{and}\quad  T'\cap G''=T'\cap T''=1.$$
Since $T'\subset Z_G$, it commutes with $G''$.
Thus $G=T'\times_{\mathbb{R}} G''$, as required.

Comment: Great! Thank you.